# C++ Union/Struct 'printColorPicker::printColorPicker(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, struct, reference, unions

Hello merciless community, i count on your help today.

Please behold the noob's code

The error is on line 20 (i'll comment it so you can see).

Error: 'printColorPicker::printColorPicker(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    enum availableColors {
        incolorPrint,
        colorPrint
    };

    union printColorPicker {
        struct incolorPrint {
            int id; 
            char* details = "No color ink eh?";
        } i;

        struct colorPrint{
            int id;
            char* details = "Unicorn mode on";
        } c;
    } color; //line 20


    void colorPicker(availableColors c){
        char* option;

        switch (c) {
        case incolorPrint: {
            option = color.i.details;
        }
        break;

        case colorPrint: {
            option = color.c.details;
        } 
        break;
        }


        cout << option;
    }



    void main(){      
        colorPicker(colorPrint);
    }
```

What i am trying to do is use the color picker method to echo/cout/printf the string inside the structs (`colorPrint`,`incolorPrint`) inside the `printColorPicker` union.

I get the above mentioned error.

Comment: So the constructor should have the name of the `union`, with no arguments?

Comment: TBH I don't get why are you using a `union` in your code at all.

Comment: It's a homework, union is one of the requirements.

Comment: Looks like they are teaching you bad things.

Comment: Sorry, my 1st comment was misleading. If you check the error messages [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d10f95745bf4135c), you see what's going wrong more clearly.

Comment: Thank you very much. in VS Comunity i get this one error, what you provided is more than useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not well versed in `union` craziness, but what is likely happening is when you provide a default value for `details` you are in fact providing a default constructor. <strike>When that happens, the `struct` is no longer an aggregate type, also known as a POD. This non-aggregate-ness propagates through, and the union is also no longer an aggregate type, which then calls the deleted default constructor on construction. (Aggregate types do not call constructor on construction, behaving exactly like a C object.)</strike>

EDIT `union` only requires that its members be trivially constructable. By providing a default value, the `struct` will no longer be trivially constructable. The difference with aggregate types being `private`/`protected` members are allowed.

The way to fix this is to remove the default values for `details` and assign to them after construction, possibly through a factory function.

BTW setting default values for different objects of a `union` makes no sense, which one should the value be?